# How to make this macro to run a range?

Tags: excel

I recorded this macro to format a datetime column as I need. I used relative references.Now when I select the entire range of the data, I run this but it only does for the first cell. Is there any way to change to run as a range?

```
 Sub Macro3()
'
' Macro3 Macro
'

'
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "6/26/2017 16:39"
    ActiveCell.Select
    Selection.NumberFormat = "h:mm:ss AM/PM"
End Sub
```

Comment: You want to put the same date in all the cells that you have selected?

Comment: no I want to format each individual cell according to the macro.We have hundreds of rows 3 times.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a good way to iterate through a selection.

```
Sub Macro3()

    Dim rngCell as Range

    for each rngCell in Selection
        rngCell = Now       
        rngCell.NumberFormat = "h:mm:ss AM/PM"  
    next rngCell

End Sub
```

You do not need to select the children (ActiveCell) in order to format them.

Comment: the only issue is it gives the same time as the first cell. I need each cell to calculate its own time.

Comment: @AccessNewbie - it gives the same time, because it is in a loop and the time is hard coded. Take a look & try again.

Comment: When I run the macro on one cell, it processes correctly for that cell.but others it is using the hhmm of the first and adding 7 seconds.

Comment: @AccessNewbie - try again the code. Select about 2000 cells in a range. The time should be different between the first and the last one.

Comment: what does this do rngCell.FormulaR1C1 = Now

Comment: @AccessNewbie - pretty much the same as `rngCell = Now` it gives the current timestamp to Excel.

Comment: oh so thats the issue we dont want the current time stamp but the time in the cell

Comment: I dont need the system time stamp i need to edit the data that is there, the date time that is our data.